# Где описать функцию, которая работает с 2мя экземплярами одного класса?

Tags: java

Есть класс, содержащий множество, например такое:

[-8.5;-8.0][-7.0;0.0][1.1;7.5]

Есть второй экземпляр такого класса со своим множеством.
Нужно найти пересечение 2-х множеств. Где описать эту функцию поиска пересечения 2-х множеств - в классе как метод, или нет?

Comment: если это не метод в классе,то что? По-моему можно в этот класс добавить метод, который принимает два объекта этого же класса и возвращает пересечение, в таком случае сделать метод статичным. Ну а второй вариант метод принимает один объект, возвращает пересечение с множеством объекта, из которого метод вызывается

Answer (score 1):

в main методе делать все ваши действия

Comment: Почему не в классе?

Comment: вы создадите два экземпляра вашего класса в main методе ,первый экземпляр будет содержать этот массив [-8.5;-8.0][-7.0;0.0][1.1;7.5], второй экземпляр свой массив. в main методе найдете и пересечение.

Comment: создайте конструктор в классе(пустой), и в main методе создайте уже два этих экземпляра этого класса.

Comment: почему не в классе, потому что, программа начнет выполнение свое с метода main. если у вас ничего не будет в методе main, то программа не отработает.